# How to use AWS WAF to protect API Gateway with HTTP APi?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-waf, aws-http-api

I am deploying an POC environment with API gateway in front of Lambda and HTTP API would be sufficient for our usage (REST API wouldn't be used). I am planning to use AWS Web application as a protection measure in front of API gateway with HTTP API to avoid unwanted inbound traffic into API gateway.

I understand that WAF shall not be supported for direct inegration with API gateway with HTTP API.
ALB can enable WAF and inegrate with HTTP API gateway as per [protection recommendations](https://www.tinystacks.com/blog-post/api-gateway-rest-vs-http-api-what-are-the-differences/). But seems WAF/ALB would be behind API Gateway HTTP API and could not prevent unwanted traffic into API gateway according to [reference architecture diagram](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/best-practices-api-gateway-private-apis-integration/http-api.html).

Would that be any integration method that WAF could be in front of HTTP API gateway or alternatives to protect HTTP API gateway from unwanted traffic?

I tried to deploy ALB and target group with HTTP API gateway but seems it would be behind the gateway which is not ideal.

Comment: Posted a solution which talks about using cloudfront with WAF to solve your problem, did it helped you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's true that HTTP API as of this moment does not support WAF unlike REST API.

You can use [CloudFront in front of your API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudfront-distribution/) and then use WAF with it.

There is a [well-architected lab from AWS](https://wellarchitectedlabs.com/security/300_labs/300_multilayered_api_security_with_cognito_and_waf/3_prevent_requests_from_accessing_api_directly/) on this which explains this in detail

Refer more for [using WAF with cloudfront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/cloudfront-features.html)

Comment: Thanks for your solution but it seems way more complicated than WAF with API gateway with REST API. Maybe I will go with the less complicated solution. :)

Comment: Yes because you mentioned http api usage so i posted a solution in respect to that. Rest API with apu gateway would always be a better solution for your requirement. Although if my answer helped you, will it be possible to accept or upvote so that it' helps others in the future with a similar problem!